# How to skip if there is no substring to avoid error in console?

Tags: jquery

I am setting substrings

```
var hash = document.location.hash;

// create an object to act like a dictionary to store each value indexed by its key
var partDic = {};

// remove the leading "#" and split into parts
var parts = hash.substring(1).split('&');

// If you just want the first value, whatever it is, use this.
// But be aware it's a URL so can be set to anything in any order, so this makes little sense
// var string = parts[0].split('=')[1];

// build the dictionary from each part
$.each(parts, function(i, v) {
// do the "=" split now
var arr = v.split("=");

// decode to turn "%5B" back into "[" etc
var key = decodeURIComponent(arr[0]);
var value = decodeURIComponent(arr[1]);

// store in our "dictionary" object
partDic[key] = value;
});

setTimeout( function() {
    var ag = partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].substring(1);
    $('.Agency .dropdown-toggle').html(ag).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
    var cl = partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"].substring(1);
    $('.Client .dropdown-toggle').html(cl).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
    var yr = partDic["comboFilters[Years]"].substring(1).slice(1);
    $('.Year .dropdown-toggle').html(yr).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
}, 1000);
```

But if there is not a substring, I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
```

I am guessing I need a simple if/else but I am not sure how to in this case

Comment: Can you post an example of the content stored within `partDic`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan question updated with full code

Comment: How about using try{} catch(){} ?

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
 var cl = (partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"] && partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"].length>0)?partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"].substring(1):'';
```

Comment: what if `partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"]` is null, will it be any exception thrown?

Comment: what if I have .slice(1) after substring, like .substring(1).slice(1) ?

Comment: you again have to check that.you can use as many ternary operators as you need just use braces to separate parts

Comment: no luck, if it has no substring i get empty text. Basically what if I have a simple url www.example.com so we have no substrings at all? However It works fine as it was with my code if substrings are there like www..ex.com/#comboFilters%5BAgencies%5D=.TBWA&comboFilters%5BClients%5D=.Vodafone&comboFilters%5BYears%5D=.y2013

Answer (score 0):

Use Condition like:

```
If(partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].length>0)
{
----your code---
}
else{}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: check what you are getting in partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].val()

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960547/how-to-skip-if-there-is-no-substring-to-avoid-error-in-console#), I got this as a solution:

```
if("comboFilters[Agencies]" in partDic) {
   var ag = partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].substring(1);
   $('.Agency .dropdown-toggle').html(ag).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
}
```