# How to skip if substring is null and avoid error in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Grab the substring:

```
var hash = document.location.hash;

// create an object to act like a dictionary to store each value indexed by its key
var partDic = {};

// remove the leading "#" and split into parts
var parts = hash.substring(1).split('&');

// If you just want the first value, whatever it is, use this.
// But be aware it's a URL so can be set to anything in any order, so this makes little sense
// var string = parts[0].split('=')[1];

// build the dictionary from each part
$.each(parts, function(i, v) {
  // do the "=" split now
  var arr = v.split("=");

  // decode to turn "%5B" back into "[" etc
  var key = decodeURIComponent(arr[0]);
  var value = decodeURIComponent(arr[1]);

  // store in our "dictionary" object
  partDic[key] = value;
});

// Set a delay to wait for content to fully load
setTimeout( function() {
  var ag = partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].substring(1);
  $('.Agency .dropdown-toggle').html(ag).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
  var cl = partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"].substring(1);
  $('.Client .dropdown-toggle').html(cl).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
  var yr = partDic["comboFilters[Years]"].substring(1).slice(1);
  $('.Year .dropdown-toggle').html(yr).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
}, 1000);
```

But if there is not a substring, I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
```

[Suggested answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960547/how-to-skip-if-there-is-no-substring-to-avoid-error-in-console)

```
var cl = (partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"] && partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"].length>0)?partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"].substring(1):'';
```

But I still get the same error

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973300/can-i-use-the-in-keyword-to-test-a-property-in-an-tree-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can be defensive and check if a key exists before using it:

```
  if("comboFilters[Agencies]" in partDic) {
       var ag = partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].substring(1);
       $('.Agency .dropdown-toggle').html(ag).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
  }
```

or just safeguard it with an empty string:

```
var ag = (partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"] || "").substring(1);
```

Comment: Like the second one.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try with things like:

```
var parts = (hash && hash.substring(1).split('&')) || [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check it's type:

```
var cl = (typeof partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"] === 'string')?partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"].substring(1):'';
```

Note, that you should add this check for all your variables: `ag`, `cl`, `yr`

Comment: that is not creating an error but it is changing the text empty

Comment: Correct, that means that `partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"]` type is not `string`. And `substring` method works only on strings. What does `console.log(partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"])` says?

Answer (score 0):

You can check one condition before using substring method..

```
if((!hash) || (!hash.substring(1)){
return false;
}
```